# Importing and Exporting Data into excel via clipboard

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, vsto, clipboard

I want to import and export 1000+ cell data into and from excel via clipboard. Also the cell data is not in a symmetric grid and the solution needs this flexibility. How do I do this?

From my research so far,

- the cell data should be in the form of tab delimited.
- use the StringBuilder to bind my data into rows of string data
- eventually bind the data to a dataobject to add it to the clipboard using the getdataobject and setdataobject methods
- use the StringSplit method to break the data down

Also I welcome suggestions if there is a better way of doing this.

I am programming in VB.net framework 4.5 but I do welcome C# solutions as well because I am also after the theory as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off the following example will not meet all your requirements but felt compelled to post as it does meet the basics for reading data from Excel from Clipboard data. So the key here is, this is a start in the right direction. In theory you should be able to reverse this to set data to the clipboard. Hope this is of some help.

```
Public Class Form1
   Private Sub cmdRun_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdRun.Click
      DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing

      Try

         Dim ClipboardData As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()

         If Not ClipboardData Is Nothing Then

            'Next proceed only of the copied data is in the CSV format indicating Excel content
            If (ClipboardData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue)) Then

               'Cast the copied data in the CommaSeparatedValue format & hold in a StreamReader Object
               Dim ClipboardStream As New IO.StreamReader(CType(ClipboardData.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue), IO.Stream))
               Dim FormattedData As String = ""

               'Define a DataTable to hold the copied data for binding to the DataGrid
               Dim Table As New DataTable With {.TableName = "ExcelData"}

               While (ClipboardStream.Peek() > 0)
                  Dim SingleRowData As Array

                  'Multipurpose Loop Counter
                  Dim LoopCounter As Integer = 0

                  'Read a line of data from the StreamReader object
                  FormattedData = ClipboardStream.ReadLine()

                  Console.WriteLine(FormattedData)

                  SingleRowData = FormattedData.Split(",".ToCharArray)

                  If Table.Columns.Count <= 0 Then
                     For LoopCounter = 0 To SingleRowData.GetUpperBound(0)
                        Table.Columns.Add()
                     Next
                     LoopCounter = 0
                  End If

                  Dim rowNew As DataRow
                  rowNew = Table.NewRow()

                  For LoopCounter = 0 To SingleRowData.GetUpperBound(0)
                     rowNew(LoopCounter) = SingleRowData.GetValue(LoopCounter)
                  Next

                  LoopCounter = 0

                  Table.Rows.Add(rowNew)

                  rowNew = Nothing
               End While

               ClipboardStream.Close()
               DataGridView1.DataSource = Table
            Else
               MsgBox("Clipboard data does not seem to be copied from Excel!")
            End If
         Else
            MsgBox("Clipboard is empty!")
         End If
      Catch exp As Exception
         MsgBox(exp.Message)
      End Try

   End Sub
   ''' <summary>
   ''' Enable if you wish, it will disable the button "Run" if there is no Excel data
   ''' in the clipboard at start up.
   ''' </summary>
   ''' <param name="sender"></param>
   ''' <param name="e"></param>
   ''' <remarks></remarks>
   Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 'Handles MyBase.Load

      Dim ClipboardData As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()

      cmdRun.Enabled = False

      If Not ClipboardData Is Nothing Then
         If (ClipboardData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue)) Then
            cmdRun.Enabled = True
         End If
      End If

      Dim dt As New DataTable With {.TableName = "CustNames"}

      dt.Columns.AddRange( _
         New DataColumn() _
            { _
               New DataColumn("FirstName", GetType(System.String)), _
               New DataColumn("LastName", GetType(System.String)) _
            } _
         )

      dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Kevin", "Gallagher"})
      DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

   End Sub
   Private Sub cmdClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdClose.Click
      Close()
   End Sub

   Private Sub Form1_Load_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      Dim dt As New DataTable With {.TableName = "CustNames"}

      dt.Columns.AddRange( _
         New DataColumn() _
            { _
               New DataColumn("FirstName", GetType(System.String)), _
               New DataColumn("LastName", GetType(System.String)) _
            } _
         )

      dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"", ""})
      DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Try
         Dim ClipboardData As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
         If Not ClipboardData Is Nothing Then
            If (ClipboardData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue)) Then
               Dim ClipboardStream As New IO.StreamReader(CType(ClipboardData.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue), IO.Stream))
               Dim FormattedData As String = ""

               'Define a DataTable to hold the copied data for binding to the DataGrid
               Dim Table As New DataTable With {.TableName = "ExcelData"}

               While (ClipboardStream.Peek() > 0)
                  Dim SingleRowData As Array
                  Dim LoopCounter As Integer = 0

                  FormattedData = ClipboardStream.ReadLine()
                  SingleRowData = FormattedData.Split(",".ToCharArray)

                  If Table.Columns.Count <= 0 Then
                     For LoopCounter = 0 To SingleRowData.GetUpperBound(0)
                        Table.Columns.Add()
                     Next
                     LoopCounter = 0
                  End If

                  Dim rowNew As DataRow
                  rowNew = Table.NewRow()

                  For LoopCounter = 0 To SingleRowData.GetUpperBound(0)
                     rowNew(LoopCounter) = SingleRowData.GetValue(LoopCounter)
                  Next

                  LoopCounter = 0

                  Table.Rows.Add(rowNew)

                  rowNew = Nothing
               End While

               ClipboardStream.Close()
               '
               ' No assertion done here for ensuring
               ' the user is attempting to paste valid
               ' data or that they are no duplicating data
               '
               If Table.Columns.Count = 2 Then
                  Dim dt As DataTable = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
                  For Each row As DataRow In Table.Rows
                     Dim rowNew As DataRow
                     rowNew = dt.NewRow()
                     rowNew("FirstName") = row(0).ToString
                     rowNew("LastName") = row(1).ToString
                     dt.Rows.Add(rowNew)
                  Next
               End If
            Else
               MessageBox.Show("Clipboard data does not seem to be copied from Excel!")
            End If
         Else
            MessageBox.Show("Clipboard is empty!")
         End If
      Catch exp As Exception
         MessageBox.Show(exp.Message)
      End Try
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hi Karen, thank you for posting your example. Any advice or example is definitely helpful. I will have a look and get back to you.

Comment: Hope it is of some use to you